# Simulating Mobile P2P network with Clustering in NS2 or Omnet++?

Tags: networking, mobile, p2p, ns2, omnet++

I want to create a mobile P2P network

- with 'n' number of nodes.
- Then according to it's location in the XY grid, nodes should self
  clustered and
- finally some searching within the P2P network should
  applied too.

Since this has been done in Mobile P2P,

- Chanel should be wireless and
- a Mobility model should applied too. This can be applied from BonnMotion Generator for NS2 though

How to do this on NS2 or Omnet++? Open to any other simulators as well.

Comment: Hi, were to able to achieve this? I'm similar work on WSN using Omnet, would you be able to help?